# JHipster: display 2 entity in same view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jhipster

how  can i do  in angular to call 2 entity services to display their data in same view.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a controller. Make sure your controller handles the event/callback/action that requests information from a service. This enables you to have x amount of services available to any controller who injects them. By giving the controller the service you can then pass on your results to the component or directive.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to inject your two entity services in your controller by adding each services in the $inject array and in the controller function parameters.
Then, you can do this in your controller:

```
YourEntityService.query(function(data) {
  vm.myentity = data;
}
```

Do this for each entity and you'll be able to display them in your view using `{{vm.myentity.name}}` for example.